# Header CSS styling spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I have a fairly simple header that I can get to look the way I want though I found that for my RWD to allow the header to work anywhere and to get the look for the whole page that want a more organized look to webpage. I am now trying the grid-template with the flexbox within the grid tracks and my header doesn't like when I want the gap between the links.  I created a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph01/vp8xnrmL/2/
I idea is the best Responsive Web Design and I keep getting the logo and the image disappearing almost completely when I change the size of the screen.
I have used the right metrics and auto where it says along with latest layouts so appreciate filling me in.

**Update**

```
.nav_menu a {
    margin: 1em 3.7em;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/sCfeeeY.png),url(https://i.imgur.com/sCfeeeY.png) ;
    background-position: top 1em right 1em, bottom 1em left 1em;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.row {
    flex: 2 auto;
    grid-column: 1 30em;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}
.active {
    margin: 1em;
}
.fullwebpage .section {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr auto auto 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(40em, 25%) 1fr; 
    grid-column: 1;
    flex: 0 1 28em;
}
.sectionheader {
    display: flex;
    flex: 8 auto;
    grid-row: auto 1;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em;
    margin-right: 3em;
}
.sectionfirst {
    padding-top: 5em;
}

.nav_menu {
    margin-right: 4em;
}
.nav_menu {
    float: left;
    justify-content: space-around;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 1;
}
.wrap {
    display: inline-flex;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:2em;
}
.wrap a {
    display: flex;
    flex: 3 auto;
    flex-flow: row;
    grid-row: 1;
    float: start;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.wrap#gsbutton {
    padding-top: .5em;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-right: 3em;
    margin-left: 0em;       
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>Frontend Challenge Developer Website</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="attributes.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <section>
        <section class="row header" id="sectionheader">
            <!-- page bar header navigation tabs -->
            <div class="head_bg">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html">
                            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4kctnTg.png"></img>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <nav class="nav_menu">
                        <a class="active" href=""><!--index.html-->Home</a>
                        <a class="active" id="pricingheader" href=""><!--pricing.html-->Pricing</a>
                        <a class="active" href=""><!--products.html-->Products</a>
                        <a class="active" href=""><!--aboutus.html-->About Us</a>
                        <a class="active" href=""><!--community-->Community</a>
                    </nav>
                    <a class="gsbutton" id="gsbutton" href="">
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/XZY4xX0.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want the section to be spaced by 1-3em.

Comment: Have you tried using padding instead? I know it's not exactly what you're looking for but padding-left:1em; and padding-right:1em; should pretty much do the same. Just add it to the a tags.

Comment: I see you have bootstrap, why not use the bootstrap nav menu and items? It will make this a lot easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `margin` on the child element instead of `padding` on your flex item.

```css
.nav_menu a {
 margin: 0 1em;
}
```

Checkout [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/harishk3499/drpcbuoj/8/)

Comment: This is what I have been doing so thinking this will totally work I have a 3 column list and when the margin for the first two are correct it no longer allows any styling on the third.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can provide width in % and since we are providing margin-left on each element, it must work on the third column as well. Do you have any working example for the problem statement?

Comment: I have the inner div, nav and img link so it's getting the entire alignment as I get one it throws the other.  Again if I don't use grid I do have it styled as responsive and looking great though the rest then does the same as the issue as this alignment does.

Comment: If you talking about same example, the last element(img link) `get started` allowing styling. `margin & padding` working on it. If you talking about the alignment issue caused by changing structure of either of element, then you have to handle it on base level.

Comment: If you want to take care of `nav-menu` item only, so that it won't affect the third element. You can do something like
`.nav_menu a {
 margin-left: 2em;
}`.. Answer updated

Comment: should I have a wrap class around the nav menu with a '.wrap a {}' and then also a '.nav_menu a {}'? Aren't they styling the same element?

Comment: .wrap a{} will include all elements under wrap class. i.e will also include `btn#gsbutton`.  But with `'.nav_menu a {}` we will target only `nav-menu` childrens i.e (nav links)

Comment: So, I see your point but the question is to evenly space the eight links. In grid this should be the template-columns. There's alternatives gap, grid-template-area and even the inner grid placing a column or row for the start or end using repeat(), minmax(), span and fractions.  Nothing is working.

Comment: Ok, I had to adjust it a little but I got that to work. Thank you. I updated the post with so many comments to not confuse users.

Answer (score -1):

All you had to do was add a bit of margin to the active class.

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/sCfeeeY.png), url(https://i.imgur.com/sCfeeeY.png);
  background-position: top 1em right 1em, bottom 1em left 1em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.a {
  padding: 2px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.row {
  flex: 2 auto;
  grid-column: 1 10em;
  grid-row: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.fullwebpage {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr auto;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-gap: 5em;
}

.sectionheader {
  display: flex;
  flex: 8 auto;
  grid-row: auto 1;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em;
  margin-right: 3em;
}

.section_bg .head_bg a:active {
  color: black;
}

.footer a:active {
  color: white;
}

.table-row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.topfooterbanner {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: 0em;
}

.nav_menu {
  float: left;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1;
}

.wrap {
  display: inline-flex;
  /* float: left; */
  /* flex: 3 auto; */
  width: 100%;
  /* margin-left: 10em; */
  margin-top: 2em;
  /* padding: 1em; */
  /* text-align: center; */
}

.wrap a {
  display: flex;
  flex: 3 auto;
  flex-flow: row;
  grid-row: 1;
  float: start;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="row header" id="sectionheader">
  <!-- page bar header navigation tabs -->
  <div class="head_bg">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4kctnTg.png"></img>
        </a>
      </div>
      <nav class="nav_menu">
        <a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a class="active" id="pricingheader" href="pricing.html">Pricing</a>
        <a class="active" href="product.html">Products</a>
        <a class="active" href="about.html">About Us</a>
        <a class="active" href="community.html">Community</a>
      </nav>
      <a class="gsbutton" id="gsbutton" href="pricing.html"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jfNTTt4.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The img that is also in the row starts changing size and doesn't place in the top right as it's styling should remain as in the third column.  The active class is only column 2.

Comment: Here look at the change in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Arandolph01/vp8xnrmL/5/